# CSS - 2 squares inside td

Tags: css

How can I have a **td** contains 2 squares inside. It kindly look like this:

[Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIOBa.png)

Sorry, I am not good in English. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a div inside the cell if that is what you need. 
Do you need the td and the inside square to have separate links or the same link?

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  }
.boxWrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: pink;
  }
.insideBox1 {
   position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  }

.insideBox2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: crimson;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="boxWrapper">
       <a href="www.google.com">
        <div class="insideBox1"></div>
       </a>
       <a href="www.yahoo.com">
         <div class="insideBox2">100</div>
       </a>
      </div>
    </td>
    
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: I would like that 2 squares inside a td and each one link to different function.

Comment: There ya go, Check the snippet in my answer above, probably a better way to do it but 2 boxes with seperate links  inside a td.

Comment: @Bhojendral Nepal - it is an answer in an answer area, not a comment.

Comment: Icewine: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Icewine You updated your answer. It's now an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery

**js Fiddle** Example [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/v4k3theh/2/)

**Snippet Example Below**

```js
$( ".Div1" ).click(function() {
  alert('Div1 Click');
});
$( ".Div2" ).click(function() {
  alert('Div2 Click');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.Div1
{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  cursor:pointer;
  
}
.Div2
{
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid black;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <diV class="Div1">
    Div1
      <div class="Div2">
      Div2
      </div>
    </diV>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code snippet

```css
#outerdiv{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100px;
  height:70px;
  position:relative;
}

#innerdiv{
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  width:50px;
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid black;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div id="innerdiv">
      100
  </div>
</div>
```

You can keep this whole thing in a td 
hope this helps